# Save Array as Map in Cloud Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array of object i am creating and saving to firestore as per the code below:

```
var user1 = [String : Any]()
var user2 = [String : Any]()
var user3 = [String : Any]()

user1.updateValue("UID1", forKey: "UserID")
user1.updateValue("John", forKey: "fName")
user1.updateValue("Smith", forKey: "lName")

user2.updateValue("UID2", forKey: "UserID")
user2.updateValue("John", forKey: "fName")
user2.updateValue("Doe", forKey: "lName")

user3.updateValue("UID3", forKey: "UserID")
user3.updateValue("Jane", forKey: "fName")
user3.updateValue("Doe", forKey: "lName")

var userDetailsArray = [[String:Any]]()

userDetailsArray.append(user1)
userDetailsArray.append(user2)
userDetailsArray.append(user3)

startCompBatch.setData(["userDetails" : userDetailsArray], forDocument: doRef, merge: true)
```

In the firestore console this is saving as follows:
[image]

This is ok but what i am trying to active is the following:
[image]

I am sure this is simple but i cant find anything that has pointed me in the correct direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it to

```
var userDetailsDict = [String:Any]()
userDetailsDict["user1"] = user1
userDetailsDict["user2"] = user2
userDetailsDict["user3"] = user3
startCompBatch.setData(["userDetails" : userDetailsDict], forDocument: doRef, merge: true)
```